# Замена некоторых элементов XML-файла на другой XML-файл с помощью XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

День добрый. Столкнулся с задачей, решение которой вызывает у меня кучу вопросов. Есть два XML-файла. Надо заменить значение из одного файла значениями другого, если у них одинаковые теги, с помощью XSLT.
вот пример первой XML-ки:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
    <tns:messageID>
        <kdm:value>AA-6rt14242-hgh-589</kdm:value>
    </tns:messageID>
    <tns:productionPlan>
        <kdm:entityKey>
                <kdm:keyA>98765</kdm:keyA>
        </kdm:entityKey>

        <kdm:specification>
            <kdm:specificationName>ProductionPlan Spec</kdm:specificationName>
            <kdm:specificationID>ProductionPlan Spec</kdm:specificationID>
            <kdm:characteristic>
                <kdm:characteristicID>SpecificationType</kdm:characteristicID>
                <kdm:characteristicValue>ProductionPlan</kdm:characteristicValue>
            </kdm:characteristic>
            <kdm:characteristic>
                <kdm:characteristicID>SpecificationType2</kdm:characteristicID>
                <kdm:characteristicValue>ProductionPlan2</kdm:characteristicValue>
            </kdm:characteristic>
            <kdm:characteristic>
                <kdm:characteristicID>CRMAuftragsNummer</kdm:characteristicID>
                <kdm:characteristicValue>1114324234</kdm:characteristicValue>
            </kdm:characteristic>
            <kdm:characteristic>
                <kdm:characteristicID>CRMAuftragsPosNummerAnschluss</kdm:characteristicID>
                <kdm:characteristicValue>111.22</kdm:characteristicValue>
            </kdm:characteristic>
            <kdm:characteristic>
                <kdm:characteristicID>Kundenwunschtermin</kdm:characteristicID>
                <kdm:characteristicValue>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</kdm:characteristicValue>
            </kdm:characteristic>
        </kdm:specification>
    </tns:productionPlan>
</tns:completeProductionPlan>
```

Вот пример второй XML-ки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:completeProductionPlan>
     <tns:messageID>
          <kdm:value>AA-6rt14242-hgh-58911</kdm:value>
     </tns:messageID>
     <tns:productionPlan> 
          <kdm:entityKey>
               <kdm:keyA>9876511</kdm:keyA>
          </kdm:entityKey>
          <kdm:specification>
               <kdm:specificationName>ProductionPlan Spec11</kdm:specificationName>
          </kdm:specification>
      </tns:productionPlan>
</tns:completeProductionPlan>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обработать несколько документов в одном xsl, используется функция `document()` ([пример 1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcombxslt/), [пример 2](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/xslt/document/)). Остальное - дело техники. После загрузки второго документа, проходимся по тегам первого и проверяем, есть ли во втором документе такой тег (тег `choose` в помощь). Если есть - записываем содержимое второго документа, если нет - первого.

Comment: Спасибо большое за инфу!)А можно как-нибудь динамически задавать имена этих xml-файлов внутри document() функции?

Comment: А передавать имена файлов в качестве параметров не устраивает? Если нет, то в XSL есть куча функций для работы со строками ([вот][1] их краткое описание)

  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: да, классно) все понятно) спасибо большое)